# Manually scaled ticks on colorbar

Tags: pgfplots

Recently, I encountered an odd error which did not allow me to rescale the ticks on the colorbar using a manually specified code.

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  colormap/viridis,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      domain=1e3:10e3,
      scaled x ticks=manual:{}{\pgfmathparse{#1/1000}},
      scaled y ticks=manual:{}{\pgfmathparse{#1/1000}},
      colorbar,
      colorbar style={
        scaled y ticks=manual:{}{\pgfmathparse{#1/1000}},
      },
    ]
    \addplot [mesh,ultra thick] {x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The `x` and `y` ticks are scaled down by a factor of 1000 (for example to change SI prefix), but does not display the scaling as that information is encoded with the unit.  The appearance of 'NaN' for the colorbar is obviously not desired and should be fixed, yet the same code that works for the axes doesn't work for the colorbar.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that the scaling does not work in the colorbar is that there are two expansions of the arguments.  In TeX, `#1` refers to the first argument (or nothing is there is no first argument), and the intention is that `#1` expands to the tick number.

The problem here is that when TeX is discovering what the argument to `colorbar style` is, it is doing a first expansion and since there are no argument, `\pgfmathparse{#1/1000}` expands to `\pgfmathparse{/1000}` which is invalid hence the NaN.

To fix this, the scaling must be specified as `\pgfmathparse{##1/1000}`.  During the problematic expansion described above, this expands to `\pgfmathparse{#1/1000}` as desired, and this can then be used to correctly scale the ticks of the colorbar:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  colormap/viridis,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      domain=1e3:10e3,
      scaled x ticks=manual:{}{\pgfmathparse{#1/1000}},
      scaled y ticks=manual:{}{\pgfmathparse{#1/1000}},
      colorbar,
      colorbar style={
        scaled y ticks=manual:{}{\pgfmathparse{##1/1000}},
      },
    ]
    \addplot [mesh,ultra thick] {x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]