# Pgfplot/Tikz colorbar expressed in percentage?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have question which may have simple answer but unfortunately I'm unable to proceed to find a solution as I'm a bit of a novice.

I'm looking to print the numbers of the colorbar of the following Tikz figure with a percentage symbol after each number. Unfortuntely as can bee seen from the MWE below this is not working.

[image: MWE example - expecting the color bar with percentage symbol after each number]

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
view={0}{90},
colormap/cool,
colorbar horizontal,
colorbar style={
at={(0,1.2)},anchor=north west,colorbar style ={yticklabel =   
\pgfmathprintnumber\tick\%}}
]
\addplot3 [surf, shader=flat] {x+y};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380167/79060

Comment: Replacing `colorbar style ={yticklabel = \pgfmathprintnumber\tick\%}}` with `xticklabel = \pgfmathprintnumber\tick\%` does the work.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.